# How can I send stanza from ejabberd server to user?

Tags: ejabberd

I am new on ejabberd. I followed this link [Ejabberd return message to sender hook / message receipts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873952/ejabberd-return-message-to-sender-hook-message-receipts) to send a message from server to user which is 6 years old. My ejabberd server crash with the given error:

```
 **exception error: no function clause matching
 xmpp:set_from_to({xmlelement,"message",[{"type","serverreceipt"},{"from","67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d"},{"to","e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2"},{"id","mty321"}],[{xmlelement,"body",[],[{xmlcdata,[]}]}]},{jid,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>},{jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"4008526814005163385914">>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"4008526814005163385914">>})
 (src/xmpp.erl, line 263)
 in function  ejabberd_router:route/3
 (src/ejabberd_router.erl, line 111)
 in call from
    mod_stanza_ack:on_user_send_packet/1
 (/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/mod_stanza_ack.erl, line 30)**
```

Is this method depreciated? or I am doing someting wrong? I am trying to do is when user A send a message to user B, when the server get the message server send an acknowledgement to user A that the server get the message.

Comment: If you provide the information that allows people to reproduce the problem, then maybe somebody can help you.

Comment: I just copy and paste the code to test the working of functions and understand how they work but getting the above error.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454410/how-to-implement-modules-in-ejabberd/63455104#63455104